# Python-django url with two slugs

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

Hello I have a problem while I am trying two slugs in one url. I have:

html file:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <h4><a class="link" href="{% url 'data:inspection_detail'
                                plant_slug=plant.slug
                                inspection_slug=inspection.slug%}">{{inspection.name}}</a></h4>
</div>
```

views.py file

```
def inspection_detail(request, inspection_slug, plant_slug):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'data/login.html')
    else:
        user = request.user
        plant = get_object_or_404(Plant, slug=plant_slug)
        inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, slug=inspection_slug)
        template = 'data/inspection_detail.html'
        context = {'inspection': inspection, 'user': user, 'plant':plant}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

and my url patterns:

```
url(r'^plants/(?P<plant_slug>[-\w])/(?P<inspection_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.inspection_detail, name='inspection_detail'),
```

But I get:

```
Page not found (404)
```

And I cant see where is the mistake!

Comment: What does the traceback say? What line does it point to?

Comment: `The current URL, plants/mel-1/{% url plant.get_absolute_url}, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: post the code where you have written the get_absolute_url function

Comment: `class Plant(models.Model): ...........     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('data:detail', args=[self.slug]) .........`

Comment: Your `plant_slug` capture group fits only one character.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

in the html file:

```
<h4><a href="{% url 'data:inspection_detail' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=inspection.id %}" >{{inspection.name}}</a></h4>
```

my views.py

```
def inspection_detail(request,slug, inspection_id):
    inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, pk=inspection_id)
    plant = get_object_or_404(Plant, slug=slug)
    recordings = Recording.objects.filter(inspection__id=inspection_id)
    template = 'data/inspection_detail.html'
    context = {'plant': plant, 'inspection': inspection, 'recordings':recordings,}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and my url file:

```
url(r'^plants/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/inspection(?P<inspection_id>[0-9]+)/create_recording$', views.create_recording, name='create_recording'),
```